# Updated! Graphics ignores $ImageResolution in v12.2 - MMA Graphics slow down with 4K monitor - Rasterize with Dynamic give problems in v12.2

Tags: graphics

Update:
I've determined that my problem is partly specific to my 4k display.  When I run the exact same code on a 2k display, I have no trouble at all, despite MMA still treating `$ImageResolution` as 144.  Additionally, some rasterized Graphics don't play well with Dynamics Graphics Primitives in v12.2.  See below

The following code is flawless in v12.0, but in v12.2 it becomes almost unresponsive with large values for `size`.  For instance, a `size` of 1500 is almost unusable on my machine in v12.2.  With the graphic open, I literally can't even use the mouse to select text inside of a MMA notebook.

```
size = 500;
Show[
 Rasterize@Graphics@Disk[], 
 Graphics@{Red, AbsolutePointSize@10,
 Dynamic@Point@MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]},
ImageSize -> size]
```

Original:
I have a GUI that is using `Show` to render a dynamically updated graphic on top of a large, rasterized graphic.  In version 12.0, this isn't an issue because you can easily set the `ImageSize` and MMA displays it accordingly.  In version 12.1 `$ImageResolution` was introduced and things get tricky.  For instance, in 12.2 (using macOS 10.14.6) `Graphics` is ignoring `$ImageResolution`, which results in a large graphics object that can cause the Front End to become very sluggish (even crash), specifically when combining the graphics with `Dynamic` content (such as a `Dynamic@MousePosition["Graphics"]`).  In the following example, setting the `$ImageResolution` doesn't work.

```
Unprotect[$ImageResolution];
$ImageResolution = 72;
Graphics[{Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 500]
ImageDimensions@%
{1000, 998}
```

Any clue how to force Graphics to use the value I'm assigning?

Note that in that example the final size of the Graphics is identical to the same code when run in 12.0, but it takes up more memory and gives me trouble when displaying larger graphics (such as over 20" wide).  In many cases it is causing MMA to completely crash.  My interactive graphics are never causing crashes in 12.0.

Also note that I know `Graphics` is the function giving the trouble, consider the following;

```
Show[
 Rasterize[ Graphics@Disk[], RasterSize -> 500],
ImageSize -> 500]
ImageDimensions@%
{500, 499}
```

```
Show[
 Rasterize[Graphics@Disk[], RasterSize -> 500],
 Graphics@{},
ImageSize -> 500]
ImageDimensions@%
{1000, 998}
```

Just including the empty `Graphics` function is enough to double the actual `ImageDimensions` of the graphic.

Answer (score 3):

`Graphics` are resolution independent, so `$ImageResolution` has no real meaning for them.  `ImageResolution` matters when you render the graphic to pixels.  i.e. it is a property of the raster.

Your original example of `ImageDimensions@Graphics[...]` equivalent to `ImageDimensions@Image@Graphics[...]`.  `Image[g_Graphics]` is an automagic conversion to a raster.  Why does `Image` ignore your setting of `$ImageResolution`?  Don't know, I would have to ask the developer for `Image`.  IIRC in 12.1 it would always use 72.

If you care about the dimensions, always use `Rasterize`.

Comment: Graphics primitives are resolution independent, but rendered Graphics in the front end are not.  The front end is using `$ImageResolution` to determine how to render the Graphics primitives in the current environment.  When you have a high resolution display, MMA is bumping `$ImageResolution` from 72 to 144.  You reference `ImageDimensions` converting the `Graphics` object to an `Image`, but the front end is basically doing the same thing when it is rendered.  In v12.2 the result is a much larger `ByteCount` for a graphic compared to v12.0, strictly due to the `$ImageResolution`.

Comment: Regarding `Rasterize`, maybe you missed the last two examples.  I rasterize my main graphic, specifying the `ImageResolution`, which gives me the control I need.  But in v12.1 and later, when combining a dynamic graphic object with the raster (using `Show`), the `Graphics` function hijacks the `ImageResolution` and the result is a much larger memory footprint, which leads to instability with the dynamic graphics objects.

Comment: The FrontEnd does not know nor cares about `$ImageResolution`.  That is simply the default value that `Rasterize` will pass to the FrontEnd when it asks the FrontEnd to rasterize something.  When the FrontEnd renders a graphic on screen, it is going to match the density of the display.

Comment: The second `Graphic` isn't hijacking anything.  The follow up call to `ImageDimensions@%` causes the output to be rasterized.  If you need convincing, try it in LinkSnooper (Evaluation > Notebook's Kernel > LinkSnooper).  You will see the Kernel calling back into the FrontEnd via `ExportPacket` when you evaluate `ImageDimensions@%`.

Comment: It is 100% the `Graphics` in `Show` that is hijacking the output, not the call to `ImageDimensions`.  I'm using `ImageDimensions` to prove it, but I can use `ByteCount` as well.  The `ByteCount` for a largely displayed `Graphics` object is much higher in 12.2 due to the `$ImageResolution`, no `ImageDimensions` call or `Rasterize` required.  I can render large identical graphics on both computers and there is a HUGE performance difference when MMA renders the graphics in 12.2 vs 12.0 due to the resolution.

Comment: Even without explicitly rasterizing the graphic, it's getting rasterized somewhere to be rendered on my screen.  When it does, it's much larger than in v12.0.  Combining that unnecessarily large graphic on screen with a dynamically update graphics primitive is the issue.

Comment: The output from `Show` is not an `Image`.  It's another `Graphics` expression, which has to be rasterized in order to figure out what it's `ImageDimensions` could be.  That puts us right back at your first example.  i.e., they are the same.

Comment: As for 12.0 and earlier vs 12.1 and later, 12.1 and later are HiDPI aware.  12.0 and earlier are not.  `CurrentValue["WindowResolution"]` will tell you resolution of the monitor the notebook is located on, which is probably more than 72dpi.  If you leave `$ImageResolution` set to `Automatic`, `Rasterize` will end up using `Max[CurrentValue[{"ConnectedDisplays", "Resolution"}]]`.  If you have an example that crashes, you should supply that example to tech support.